# Could not open socket when sending mail on localhost

Tags: sockets, zend-framework, email, xampp, localhost

Hi I am using zend framework on my local PC for one my project. For this I am using xampp on windows. I am having this kind of error :

Exception information:

Message: Could not open socket

Stack trace:

## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp.php(167): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_connect('ssl://smtp.gmai...')

## 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\library\Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp.php(199): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->connect()

## 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\library\Zend\Mail\Transport\Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()

## 3 C:\xampp\htdocs\library\Zend\Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))

smtp details are fine because its working on other local pc.

Please help me.

Thanks